# Turn DEBUG messages off in drmaa-python

Tags: python, debugging, drmaa

I am using DRMAA python bindings (see here http://code.google.com/p/drmaa-python/) to manage distributed jobs via Condor on a cluster.

I cannot find a way to turn off the DEBUG messages that the code prints to the terminal.

For example:

DEBUG: Now waiting for...
DEBUG: drmaa_join_files
DEBUG: Join_files is set
DEBUG: drmaa_block_email: 1

Any ideas?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The [source code](http://code.google.com/p/drmaa-python/source/browse/) does not contain any of the strings you provided as example, so the message may come from the DRMAA C library that you use through drmaa-python.

I would recommend to test the DRMAA library of your DRM system with a small C program, and see if you still get the DEBUG messages.

If this is the case, then you need to reconfigure your actual DRMAA library.

If the C application does not give you the messages, then you use a version of drmaa-python not corresponding to the source trunk. In this case, it may help to play around with the [Python logging facility configuration](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial).